# Difference between the two scenarios mentioned below?

Tags: javascript

**CASE 1:**

```
fetch('/foo')
   .then((res) => console.log(res), err => console.log(err))
```

**CASE 2:**

```
fetch('/foo')
   .then(res => console.log(res))
   .catch(err => console.log(err))
```

What is the difference between both these cases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the first one is without chaining and the second one

```
fetch('/foo')
       .then(res => console.log(res))
      .catch(err => console.log(err))
```

is using promise chaining and `.catch` really means `.then(null, handler)`

check [this MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises#Chaining) (under **chaining** section)

> ... 
> The arguments to `then` are optional, and `catch(failureCallback)` is short for `then(null, failureCallback)`. You might see this expressed with arrow functions instead:

In other words, the second one is simply a short hand for:

```
fetch('/foo')
       .then(res => console.log(res))
       .then(null, err => console.log(err))
```

So the difference is simply the use of chaining.